# How to share Information between MVC-Application and Console Application

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, oauth-2.0

I am working on an application that works with OAuth2.0. The Authentication process is made in a Webapplication (MVC). My API calls, are made from a Console Application. Since the Authentication process is seperated from the API calls, I need a way to share the token with my console application which uses it for signing the API requests.

What are best practices of sharing Data between two seperated Applications like mine? I would like it to be safe so just storing my token in a file and reading from the file again is not really an option. I also do not want to build a Database just for this.

Comment: Why are you using a Console Application to do the API calls?

Comment: No special reason for it to be a Console Application. It should just be seperated since it's going to be added to a framework later, which requires that.

Comment: You can make the API calls a library and just use the class library from your MVC (Import the reference). So whatever framework you want to put it in can also using the class library. You can also write a bunch of tests for the library to make sure the API calls work for who ever is using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using Microsoft Message Queuing (MSMQ)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Does this work for Applications running simultaneously?

Comment: Absolutely, that's what it is designed for. Let one application listen on a queue, and the other application send the token into the queue.